# how to define a new suffix with vscode?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, jsx

Why are suffixes like “.vue” and “.jsx” recognized and processed by vscode? If I want to customize a suffix called “.xxx” with an icon and process it, how should I do it?

I want to get a practical tutorial or guide document, if there is a detailed explanation of the principle, I will be very grateful

Comment: You'd need to develop a plugin

Comment: As @mousetail said you would need to create an extension. [More information](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)